# pandas timestamp year month cannot access directly

Tags: python, pandas

I got a column named 'datetime'.And the datatype is object.
[image]

I want to access the month by

```
bikeshare['datetime'].dt.month
```

But I got the error.  [image]

I tried to access by following. It doesn't work either.

```
bikeshare['datetime'].month
```

The only successful way I did is

```
bikeshare['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(bikeshare['datetime'])
bikeshare['datetime'].dt.year
```

[image]

I am confused about this. Because the original 'datetime' is timestamp if my understanding is correct.But why I cannot access the attribute directly?

Comment: because the `dtype` of the datetime field is not a datetime when you read the data set , rather an `object`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after

DataFrame

```
print(bikeshare)
                  datetime  season
    0  2011-01-01 00:00:00       1
    1  2011-01-01 01:00:00       1
    2  2011-01-01 02:00:00       1
```

Check dtypes

```
 bikeshare.dtypes

datetime    object
season       int64
dtype: object
```

Extract Month

```
bikeshare['months']=pd.to_datetime(bikeshare['datetime']).dt.month
print(bikeshare)



              datetime  season  months
0  2011-01-01 00:00:00       1       1
1  2011-01-01 01:00:00       1       1
2  2011-01-01 02:00:00       1       1
```

Comment: Do you know why it has to transform the original 'datetime' column by using  pd.to_datetime? The original column is timestamp which should have the day,month and year attribute.

Comment: Please remember timestamp can either be string or datetime object. Either  is valid. It happens you have an string here. That is how it was read in and you have to convert.

Comment: But using df. dtypes , the original 'datetime'  column is object type. I am not sure how to tell the type of this column now.